# validation not working in live server laravel 8

Tags: laravel, validation

I am working with laravel 8 . When user register using already existing email give validation error properly as "the email is already exists" . but in the live server give duplicate entry sql error.

```html
  Validator::make($input, [
            'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
        ])->validate();
```

Comment: PLEASE, add some code and errors. Something is not working doesn't make any sense if code is not provided!

Comment: did you get your solution, I'm having the same error

Answer (score 1):

you can use validation on controller like this

```
$validated = $request->validate([
        'first_name' =>'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'email' =>  'required|unique:posts|max:255',
         'password' => 'required',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the field name in the database table is email only. If it is something else, then you will have to write the validation like this:

```
'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users, field_name'],
```